# PHP mail script not working

Tags: php, email, configuration, sendmail

I downloaded this php mail script:

```
<?php
/*
From http://www.html-form-guide.com 
This is the simplest emailer one can have in PHP.
If this does not work, then the PHP email configuration is bad!
*/
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    /* ****Important!****
    replace name@your-web-site.com below 
    with an email address that belongs to 
    the website where the script is uploaded.
    For example, if you are uploading this script to
    www.my-web-site.com, then an email like
    form@my-web-site.com is good.
    */

    $from_add = "myemail@myemail.com"; 

    $to_add = "myemail@myemail.com"; //<-- put your yahoo/gmail email address here

    $subject = "Test Subject";
    $message = "Test Message";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


    if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
       $msg = "Error sending email!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test form to email</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<p>
<form action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

I am just using `myemail@myemail.com` as a substitute for my email in the code.

I am running OSX 10.7.5, using the built in web server in the system preferences. I load the page samplemail.php from http://xxx.home/~xxx/samplemail.php (`xxx` is being substituted for my username).

I click submit - and it displays "Mail Sent OK" as it should. However, the email never gets delivered.

I'm assuming this is a configuration problem.

I've done `php --ini` in the terminal and it tells me `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/local/etc/php54`

I edited the php.ini file (located in `/opt/local/etc/php54`), so that it knows where `sendmail` is:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

I have verified that `sendmail` is located at `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into the same issue with the built in webserver.  While the sendmail_path is there it will throw errors.  Upload it to a live environment and retry.  I'm still not sure if it was a mail server on the other end filtering me [as I know some will], or if it was another error, but putting the script on an actual webserver solved the issue for me.

The script is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use third-party libraries such as [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) for send emails,  it's more stability.